# AJAX Testing Tools

Tags: javascript, windows, ajax, linux, testing

I am looking for Ajax testing tools . is there any free tools avilable for testing ajax

Edit 2 : apart from firebug is there any other tools ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with jQuery and are looking for unit testing, then [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit) is decent and helps prevents the obvious bugs. As far as getting the right data back from the server, you will probably want to combine it with unit tests to ensure the server's data is correct.

Here's an example from some [jQuery extensions](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-extensions/) I've written:

```
function run()
{
    module("Extensions");
    test("isNumber", function()
    {
        var anInt = new Number(42);
        var aFloat = new Number(42.500);
        equals(jQuery.isNumber(anInt),true);
        equals(jQuery.isNumber(aFloat),true);

        equals(jQuery.isNumber(42),true);
        equals(jQuery.isNumber(42.235),true);

        equals(jQuery.isNumber("test"),false);
        equals(jQuery.isNumber([]),false);
        equals(jQuery.isNumber(true),false);
        equals(jQuery.isNumber(undefined),false);
        equals(jQuery.isNumber(null),false);
    });
}

run();
```

Answer (score 2):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox is the most common answer. Combine that with [firephp](http://www.firephp.org/) for server side debugging. It works great for AJAX scripts as well.

Comment: i am looking for apart from firebug

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) when looking at XMLHttpRequests.

If you are on a mac, there is [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)